# How to compare two tables and select the differences in the order?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got two tables which are almost identical, tho the order of some rows are mixed up between the two tables. I will give you an example how my tables might look like:

`table 1`:

```
colum1 | colum2 | colum3
-------+--------+-----------
test1  | pizza  | margarita 
test1  | pizza  | cheese    
test1  | pizza  | hawaii    
test1  | burger | salad     
test2  | pizza  | margarita 
test2  | pizza  | ham       
test2  | burger | tomat     
test2  | burger | salad     
test3  | pig    | green     
test3  | cow    | green     
test3  | cow    | yellow    
test3  | pig    | bird
```

`table 2`:

```
colum1 | colum2 | colum3
-------+--------+------------
test1  | pizza  | margarita 
test1  | pizza  | hawaii      <-- different spot than before
test1  | pizza  | cheese      <-- different spot than before 
test1  | burger | salad     
test2  | pizza  | margarita 
test2  | pizza  | ham       
------ | ------ | ---------  <-- no value between those (so its missing)
test2  | burger | salad     
test3  | pig    | green     
test3  | cow    | green     
test3  | cow    | yellow    
test3  | pig    | bird
```

So as you can see in the tables above, there is a row mixed and there is a missing row. Now I want to make a query like the following: "*if colum1 is the same, then check if the rows are in the same order as the other table*" if this isn't true, "*show all the rows as long as colum1 has the same values.*" So the result would be this:

```
         table1                    table2
------+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------
test1 | pizza | margarita | test1 | pizza | margarita 
test1 | pizza | cheese    | test1 | pizza | hawaii        <<<shows all `test1` because this one is different
test1 | pizza | hawaii    | test1 | pizza | cheese    
test1 | burger| salad     | test1 | pizza | salad     
test2 | pizza | margarita | test2 | pizza | margarita 
test2 | pizza | ham       | test2 | pizza | ham       
test2 | burger| tomat     |       |       |               <<<shows all `test2` because this one is different
test2 | burger| salad     | test2 | burger| salad
```

Also: one row(so colum1, colum2, colum3 combined) is always identical.

So, Is this somehow possible with SQL? or should I use something else for this to do?

Comment: what do you mean by *order* here?

Comment: Table data is unordered.

Comment: This is a simple orderd full outer join, where filtering out nulls on one of the second table columns. Bonus: The is no sense "if one column same, then check all columns are same", simple go for "all columns are same

Comment: There is no such thing as "the order of a table". Rows in a relational database are **NOT** "sorted". The only way to get a sorted _output_ is to use an `order by` in a select statement

Comment: @jarlh This is true, the table data will be delivered unordered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: You need to have an index so a bad id to generate it is using this code:
>
> ```
> row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as rowId
> ```

But if you want to track changes between those tables you can use a query like this:

```
;with t1 as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as rowId
    from table1
), t2 as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as rowId
    from table2
), t as (
select t1.rowId, t1.colum1, t1.colum2, t1.colum3
    , coalesce(t2.rowId - t1.rowId, 999999999) + sum(case when t2.rowId is null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by t1.rowId) cs
from t1 full outer join t2 
  on t1.colum1 = t2.colum1 and t1.colum2 = t2.colum2 and t1.colum3 = t2.colum3 
)
select t.colum1, t.colum2, t.colum3,
    case when t.cs >= 999999999 then 'skipped'
         when t.cs = 0 then ''
         else 'replaced'
    end table2State
from t
order by t.rowId;
```

That results like this:

```
colum1  | colum2    | colum3    | table2State
--------+-----------+-----------+--------------
test1   | pizza     | margarita |
test1   | pizza     | cheese    | replaced
test1   | pizza     | hawaii    | replaced
test1   | burger    | salad     |
test2   | pizza     | margarita |
test2   | pizza     | ham       |
test2   | burger    | tomat     | skipped
test2   | burger    | salad     |
test3   | pig       | green     |
```

Comment: This almost works. Tho when I switch the `test3 | pig | green` with the `test3 | pig | bird` it doenst give the correct answer. So it looks like it only detects a switch if the value is below or under itself. When colum1 has the same values, it could be switched in those values.So the values between the `test1` and `test2` and `test3` can switch. but they cant switch outside those. So in this example `pizza | margarita` can switch to 3 other places

Answer (score 0):

Left/right join the tables with ordering and row_number function with all of the columns you wish to compare plus ordered number and there will be nulls where the tables are different.

Comment: But that order difference is lost.

Comment: you can add order by :
(select * from t1 order by 1) x left join (select * from t2 order by 1) y on ...

Comment: But that is not what OP is asking for.

Comment: sorry, you are right. 
a row_number has to be added